# Accessing WebService from Android using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

After searching for a whole day I still cannot find a solution to my problem.

I have an WebService, which gives me the following [WSDL file](http://pastebin.com/Cv7wDpuS), that i uploaded to pastebin cause it's really big.

For the beginning I'd like to implement the ping function, which you call with a string value and which returns the string value to the client. I think the relevant parts are:

```
<wsdl:operation name="ping">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ping" name="ping"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:pingResponse" name="pingResponse"></wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:ServerException" name="ServerException"></wsdl:fault>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:UserException" name="UserException"></wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and:

```
<xs:complexType name="ping">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="in" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Anyway it would be very nice if you could look at the actual wsdl file and tell me if these are REALLY the relevant parts of it.

So, to access this with Android I'm using ksoap2. My Code looks as followed:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://shared.bimserver.org/", "ping");
request.addProperty("in", "Hallo Welt");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.0.0.5:8082/soap");
httpTransport.debug = true;
httpTransport.call("http://shared.bimserver.org/ping", envelope);
```

This creates the following request:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><ping xmlns="http://shared.bimserver.org/" id="o0" c:root="1"><in i:type="d:string">Hallo Welt</in></ping></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

But I get this response:

```
<soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://shared.bimserver.org/", local:"in"). Expected elements are &lt;{}in> </faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body>
```

So I expect, that the parameter "in" mustn't have a namespace. I tried different things like:

```
PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
info.setName("in");
info.setNamespace("");
info.setValue("Hallo Welt");
request.addProperty(info);
```

But this didn't change the request or the response.

I also removed the namespace from the soap object:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("", "ping");
```

Which gives me following request:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><ping xmlns="" id="o0" c:root="1"><in i:type="d:string">Hallo Welt</in></ping></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

And following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unexpected wrapper element ping found.   Expected {http://shared.bimserver.org/}ping.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So here it seems, that the parameter "in" must NOT have a namespace, but the ping request MUST have one.

Please help me. I've tried anything I can imagine.

**EDIT:** With soapUI I found out, that the response should look like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:shar="http://shared.bimserver.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <shar:ping>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <in>Hallo</in>
      </shar:ping>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My request looks like this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <ping xmlns="http://shared.bimserver.org/">
      <in i:type="d:string">test</in>
    </ping>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

How do I get my request to look like the needed request?

Comment: How did you solve your problem ? would you like to share ?

Comment: Unfortunately not at all. It's been some time but if I remember correctly I switched implementing some parsing by myself. Sorry to be of no big help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make request for .Net web service and here I am calling function named "Login" and you can find name space for your service in soap envelop format shown in function link line    so here "http://www.example.com/" in namespace and function name id Login. For more details check [this](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/w/list) link

```
    private static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/service.asmx";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+"Login";
    final String METHOD_NAME ="Login";
    String response=null;
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("username",user_name);
        request.addProperty("password", password);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
        marshal.register(envelope);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive soap_primitive = null;
            soap_primitive=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            response=String.valueOf(soap_primitive);
```

Comment: this did't solve my problem. I need to know how the request must look like for the server to accept it. I always get SoapFault. Anyway thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace of the property:

```
PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
info.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
info.setName("in");
info.setValue("Hallo Welt");
info.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
request.addProperty(info);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did't work either. this gives me the following response: 

`<soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", local:"in"). Expected elements are &lt;{}in> </faultstring></soap:Fault>`

Comment: another reason might be about the blank between "Hallo" and "Welt". Services would sometimes occure a problem because of that. remove the blank

Comment: No thats also not the problem. the problem is that i have to get the namespace declaration into the envelope tag and than do it like <ns:ping>...</ns:ping>. but this doesn't seem to work with ksoap2.